# Navigation bar title jumping right after flip transition

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, transition, uinavigationitem

I have a simple UIViewController with a simple view. As a result of a user interaction, a new UINavigationViewController is instantiated and its view is being added as a subview to the view of the UIViewController. This takes place as part of an aninmation transition (flip).

This works quite well and the first view is flipped over in favor of the second view. But when the animation comes to an end (the UINavigationViewController's view fills the whole screen) the navigation bar items jump, i.e. the title jumps about 5-10 pixel from right to left, the buttons' jump depending on which side (left / right) they are positioned. During the animation you can see that the buttons are misplaced and that the jumping movement is kind of a repositioning.

Could anyone tell me the reason for this and give me some advice how to avoid this?

Comment: It doesn't seem to depend on the flip transition. If I use UIViewAnimationTransitionNone I still can see that the title is moving. This time it seems as if the whole title move in from the right (similar to when you are pushing and dropping to and from the UINavigationController).

Comment: I'm having the same problem except I'm using a standard push (nav controller) segue.

Answer (score 3):

This is a little late, but there's no accepted answer and I've encountered this issue even fairly recently (albeit with an older app running on iOS 8).

If you encounter this issue and also see a warning along the lines of the following, it may be that you haven't properly set your root view controller in the app delegate:

> Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the
>   end of application launch

Modifying the app delegate as follows recently remedied the issue for me:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Other logic goes here
    // ...

    self.window.rootViewController = myRootViewController; // This was missing

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

(I previously had some nearly-equivalent code that was setting up the view so everything displayed correctly on launch, but was not specifically setting the window's root view controller.)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's annoying, but I have no idea why it happens, but in my experience, it happens in one of two cases:

1. Translucent navigationBar: maybe it had something to do with the fact that a translucent navigationBar sometimes sets a view's wantsFullScreen property (the view will then extend below the navigationBar).
2. During transitions: as you have described.

To avoid it, maybe a nice animation to fade it on an off screen before and after animation so as not to give the illusion of low quality.

OR

In viewWillAppear, assign the pixel value it's jumping to the navigationBar's origin.y. It's sad that it happens, but sometimes it just can't be fixed any other way.

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by partially-corrupt PNGs used for navigation bar buttons when the UIImages are resizableWithEdgeInsets:. If you're using custom button item images, try exporting them again using techniques known to produce reliable images (See blog posts by Marc Edwards at Bjango for a good start).

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a problem that sounds identical to what you were experiencing.   I found that using the `[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{}]` block inside of `transitionWithView` fixed it.

[During custom segue transition, view's navigation bar items are misplaced](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26127915/2418006).